# Need assistance creating a PowerShell command for Registry

Tags: powershell, registry

I am not very familiar with creating PowerShell commands. I am in need of assistance. In order to get some application data over to the EventViewer as a security audit, I have enabled it through the Registry. I am trying not to do this change manually to all the company devices. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I have done - `Computer\HKEY_USERS\SID\SOFTWARE\ApplicationName\App`
Under the `Advanced` tab (`Advanced Security Settings for App`), `Auditing` Tab is enabled for all users.
(Type: All, Principal: `Everyone`, Access: `Full Control`, Applies to: `This key and subkeys`)

Thank you in advance for any help.

RegistrySnip
[image]

Comment: I would recommend asking this question on https://serverfault.com, but you can use GPOs to deploy registry changes to some or all of your domain joined servers.

Comment: I know but I am currently in a cloud infrastructure and I only have Intune to deploy. The configuration profiles there for windows are very limited.

Answer (score 0):

Registry keys have their own audit rule types compared to file system audit rules, but can be set in a pretty similar way:

```
$RegPath = "\Printers\Connections"

# example to get the currently logged-on user: (in DOMAIN\Username format). 
# note: returns nothing if multiple users logged in (through RDP etc)
$LoggedOnUser = (Get-CimInstance -class Win32_ComputerSystem).username

# split the domain section of the username off:
$Username = ($LoggedOnUser -split '\\')[1]

# Get user SID
$SID = ([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]($LoggedOnUser)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value

# Check if user registry loaded already and use it:
if (Test-Path Registry::HKEY_USERS\$SID\) {
  $UserReg = "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$SID"
}

# Otherwise load it manually (may not work if user is logged in)
else {
  # load the user's registry hive to an easy to find path:
  REG LOAD "HKEY_USERS\$Username" "C:\Users\$Username\NTUSER.DAT"
  # Now you can search their registry
  $UserReg = "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$Username"
}

# Read the current ACL
$acl = Get-ACL "$UserReg$RegPath" -Audit

# Set the rule parameters as needed
$Identity         = "Everyone"
$Rights           = 'FullControl'
$InheritanceFlags = "ContainerInherit"
$PropogationFlags = "None"
$AuditFlags       = "Success"

$NewRule = [System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAuditRule]::new($Identity,$Rights,$InheritanceFlags,$PropogationFlags,$AuditFlags)

$ACL.SetAuditRule($NewRule)
$ACL | Set-Acl "$UserReg$RegPath"
```

Comment: Would I be able to use \$SID\  as would it apply to any user logged in?

Comment: @Mknight Do you want to set it on all users profiles, only the current logged-in user, or a specific user name? I've added how to get the SID for a specific user to my answer, but you could also do `$SIDs = Get-ChildItem 'Registry::HKEY_USERS\' | Where Name -NotLike '*Classes'` then substitute the registry paths with `Foreach ($SID in $SIDs) { $RegPath = Join-Path $SID.PSPath '\Software\AppName\App'; #rest of script }`

Comment: The way this application sub app folder works, it only appears for the current logged in user. So if it could be applied to any currently logged in user would be amazing. Thank you so much for all the communication.

Comment: @Mknight I edited my answer to use the currently logged-on user. (It only expects one user though, so it will fail if you have another user logged on via remote desktop for example). If this gets you what you need, don't forget to mark it as the answer, thanks!

Comment: I tried that code and added the application name in there. The following error what I received.                                                                                                                     
Get-ACL : Cannot find path 'Registry::HKEY_USERS\\SOFTWARE\AppName\App' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:8
+ $acl = Get-ACL $RegPath -Audit
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

Comment: @Mknight you can see in `...HKEY_USERS\\Software` that the script did not set `$SID` correctly. Try and run the commands for `$loggedOnUser` and `$SID` manually and see which one isn't working correctly. Also try running `quser` to list the user sessions, and see if there might be more than one user logged in.

Comment: It looks like it returned the same results. `Registry::HKEY_USERS\\SOFTWARE\Zscaler\App' because it does not exist.` I did also try, `HKCU:\SOFTWARE\AppName\App` and got this error `HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Zscaler\App' because it does not exist` Would any of it be because the advance settings auditing is not enabled yet? When using the second line `$acl = Get-ACL $RegPath -Audit`

Comment: Quick update. If I run the following command as the local user and not Admin in PowerShell `Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\SOFTWARE\AppName\App`. I get results but not as the admin, but under admin the error, because it does not exist. Following the same above as a local user I then get a not authorized when trying to access the next line for. `$acl = Get-ACL $RegPath -Audit`

Comment: @Mknight Run `Get-CimInstance -class Win32_ComputerSystem | fl *` on its own and verify that the `UserName` field is not blank. If it IS blank, then you'll want to use a different command to find the current local user(s) like `Get-CimInstance -class win32_loggedOnUser | Select -ExpandProperty Antecedent -Unique`. You just need the username to get the SID, and you need the SID to search the correct registry location.

Comment: I do see the username and I can pull the SID from the test machine that I am using. I did try the SID yesterday and I get the same error. `Get-ACL : Cannot find path
'Registry::HKEY_USERS\HKEY_USERS\SID#Removed\SOFTWARE\SoftwareApp\App' because it
does not exist.
At line:1 char:8
+ $acl = Get-ACL $RegPath -Audit
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand`

Comment: @Mknight it looks like you have a typo: `Registry::HKEY_USERS\HKEY_USERS\$SID` should be `Registry::HKEY_USERS\$SID`

Comment: I believe I mistyped when I pasted it. Whenever the `Get-Acl` command goes in no matter what I try in different variations it comes back with a `because it does not exist`. Would there be an easier way to just enable auditing on all software applications for any user?

Comment: @Mknight stupid mistake on my part... my setup was automatically loading the user's registry, but I found that doesn't usually happen depending on how/where you're running your script. I've updated my answer to use `REG LOAD` first, and now you shouldn't need to find the SID anymore. You know this already too, but I'll note here that powershell must be elevated/running as admin to read the NTUSER.DAT file for other users.

Comment: sorry for the prolonged reply. Some additional things came up and I was not able to test. Here is what I have gotten back. The `REG LOAD` gives ERROR Invalid key name. Searching that is looks to require `ROOTKEY Subkey`.

Comment: @Mknight it sounds like `$username` didn't get set properly.

Comment: I went ahead and made sure that the auditpol for the registry was enabled and went down the script, line by line. When I get to the `REG LOAD` part I am getting the error `ERROR: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` . After that, the `$acl = Get-Acl $RegPath -Audit` comes back with `Cannot find path because it does not exist` . I can see the audit tab in the registry for the account.

Comment: @Mknight I've updated my answer - I was using this in the past for something else and found that IF a user is logged on and active, THEN their registry should be loaded with their SID and will be locked. If not, then a user's profile must be loaded manually with `reg load`. I tried this `if/else` in a handful of different situations, and it now always accesses the user's registry correctly. I had to adjust it for the answer so it might have typos