# Remotely running a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, administrator

This script only works when ran manually on a administrative user of a system.
Im wondering how I can run this script remotely on multiple computers? I use an automation manager with powershell capabilities and this part of the script won't add these values to the registry.

```
If (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]'Administrator')) {
    Write-Host "You didn't run this script as an Administrator. This script will self elevate to run as an Administrator and continue."
    Start-Sleep 1
    Write-Host "                                               3"
    Start-Sleep 1
    Write-Host "                                               2"
    Start-Sleep 1
    Write-Host "                                               1"
    Start-Sleep 1
    Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList ("-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"{0}`"" -f $PSCommandPath) -Verb RunAs
    Exit
}
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'

Function ABC{

    REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /v HiberbootEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
    Write-Output "completed"

    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" -Name "EnableAutoTray" -Type DWord -Value 0
    Write-Host "Done - Now showing all tray icons"

    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" -Name "HideFileExt" -Type DWord -Value 0

    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search" -Name "SearchboxTaskbarMode" -Type DWord -Value 1

    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Feeds" -Name "EnableFeeds" -Type DWord -Value 0

    Set-ItemProperty -Path  "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Feeds" -Name "ShellFeedsTaskbarViewMode" -Type DWord -Value 2

    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\People" -Name "PeopleBand" -Type DWord -Value 0

    }
    Stop-Process -name explorer -Force

ABC
```

Comment: `HKCU` refers to the registry settings for the Current User. Is the script running *as* the user who needs these values changed?

Comment: I just tried `HKLM`. Works only locally. Could I be that I have to change first line to System user?

Comment: To make clearer what @Cpt.Whale said - `HKCU` does _not_ mean "the user that is currently logged on locally to a remote computer". It literally means _current user_ (i.e., the user that's running the code).

Comment: Depending on how your "automation manager" invokes scripts on remote machines you may have to remove the admin check at the top completely - re-launching with `Start-Process` in a remote session means you won't be able to consume any output.

Comment: I use N-able automation manager. How would you specify an invoke command to run this on multiple devices?

Comment: @Deffjm, are you in a domain environment? This would be very simple to do using GPO instead if you can. These user preference settings cannot easily be set via remote ps session like `Invoke-Command`. If you need to though, you can try loading the user's registry like https://stackoverflow.com/a/68776352/7411885

Comment: AAD, AD and local admin accounts. I'll check that out!